Why does Generalized Mean Pooling (GeM) become Max Pooling as  approaches infinity?
I've been studying various pooling methods in neural networks and came across Generalized Mean Pooling (GeM), which is defined as:

where pis a parameter that determines the type of pooling.
I understand that different values of p yield different pooling results. For example, when p=1, GeM becomes average pooling, and when p=2, it becomes root mean square (RMS) pooling.
However, I'm struggling to understand why GeM turns into max pooling when p approaches infinity. Could someone provide a detailed mathematical explanation or proof to help me understand this concept?
Thank you!

Hi, you have a proof on the wikipedia page even if they do not give a lot of details...  Maybe try the case with only 2 elements in the sum in the first place to get the intuition.
